# Need an explanation on how did the lecturer get this answer in this recursive problem

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

```
void rec(char *s) {
    if (s[0] == 0) return;

    rec(s + 1);

    printf("%c", s[0]);
    
    rec(s + 1);

    printf("X");
}
```

The input is "1234" and the supposed answer is `4X34XX24X34XXX14X34XX24X34XXXX`.

I tried tracing the code by hand but just couldn't get the answer that was set by the lecturer.

Comment: What does the routine print if the string contains a single character? What does it print if the string contains two characters, including the recursive calls? What does it print if the string contains three characters?

Comment: Can you show how you manually traced it? Maybe we'll spot your error.

Comment: Soon you will see this kind of recursion in post-order and in-order tree traversal algorithm.

Comment: _"but just couldn't get the answer"_ - that's odd because I get exactly the same output as the lecturer got. Where did it break the pattern for you? Perhaps intenting it with the depth helps? https://godbolt.org/z/z4cEoos1c

Comment: So i was using only the first char of the input when solving it on paper ("1" for first call) instead of the whole string ("1234") and lost in all the indents. Figured it out now. Thanks for the help folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to trace 31 calls of `rec()`, which is kind of tedious and prone to error. It is better to figure out what a call to `rec()` *does*, and then construct the output based on that.

Think about calling `rec()` with one character. Let's say "4". Then you get: `4X`. Now how about two? Consider "34". We will get the result of "4" twice, before and after the "3", followed by an "X". So, with some spaces and parentheses for clarity, `(4X) 3 (4X) X`. Now for "234", we get that, before and after a "2", followed by an "X". So the construction working backwards is to take the previous result, copy it, put in the current character, copy the previous result again, and then append an "X":

`4X`

`(4X) 3 (4X) X`

`((4X) 3 (4X) X) 2 ((4X) 3 (4X) X) X`

`(((4X) 3 (4X) X) 2 ((4X) 3 (4X) X) X) 1 (((4X) 3 (4X) X) 2 ((4X) 3 (4X) X) X) X`

Now removing the parentheses and spaces, we get:

`4X34XX24X34XXX14X34XX24X34XXXX`

Answer (score 0):

recursion is printing something on left then, s[0] is being printed, then recursion is printing something on right then X is being printing.

it's like this:

(something)1(something)X

now both something will be same because same calls being made.

now keep looking inside something same pattern follows.

in each something there will be another something

previous something = (another something)2(another something)X

look at it like this you will be able to see what is happening

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).